# How to avoid conflict of two scheduled jobs causing ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two different scheduled cron jobs which runs every 15 mins and finishes the job within 60 sec. Both act on the same enity: read then process and then save the entitiy using JpaRepository save method and it is causing below error

```
org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [nl.coin.comp.domain.ServiceProvider] with identifier [105]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [nl.coin.comp.domain.ServiceProvider#105]
```

As a fix i want to avoid the conflict between both jobs. I was thinking to used @Scheduled(fixedelay) different fixed delay for both but they can overlap as well.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Try again? That's what you normally do when optimistic locking fails.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i don't want to retry as my application will be running on different nodes and has same db so in case job of 1 node does the task i am fine with this exception But within the same application instance i want to avoid the conflict between two jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pessimistic lock. Add `select for update` in transaction for the entity. The second one should wait till the end of transaction 1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Applying pessimistic lock will prevent other part of application to read the same row. I am thinking of applying application level synchronized block with shared lock between two job.so if on job has acquired the lock then other will wait. The only cons i see that both job wont run concurrently and one will wait util other completes.

Comment: It's a potential leak. Suppose you run the 2 jobs on different nodes. I would also suggest to introduce kind of status for the entity. Set it to `in progress` just after start job and let another job wait till the status is released.